# Eclipse IDE Kotlin plugin project building error

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install the kotlin plugin on my Eclipse IDE but get an error like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1N4g.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZE6Y.png)

I tried deleting and reinstalling the plugin but that didn't fix it.I also tried creating a separated workspace for kotlin projects but that didn't solve it either.After that i did some research and found out many people have problems with this plugin so is this issue related to my pc or the plugin is just broken?